# Why was this question closed (and also why not migrated)?

Tags: discussion, migration

[Why do console games require a button press before showing the main menu?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/18780/why-do-console-games-require-a-button-press-before-showing-the-main-menu)

Seems like a perfectly fine question, but it may be a bit development-themed, so if it is considered really off-topic, it should be migrated to Gamedev.SE.

This question is definitely of interest to gamers, as it has so many upvotes.

---

I see that there's a rule on SE to not migrate old questions. The question of closing still remains.

Comment: Migration requires a mod.  We can't vote for migration.

Comment: Can we discuss if it is an option and then maybe flag it?

Comment: Meta was the right place to come.  I was just letting you know why it was closed instead of migrated. Our mods will have to talk to their mods.

Comment: Old questions are not migrated, per SE policy.

Comment: Another question is "why close at all" - this is something I have always been curious about, as a gamer (and not a game developer), so I think it's a great question.

Comment: The question comes from a time when our sites standards were substantially less stringent than they are today. Questions of the "Why does mechanic exist" flavor are *generally* frowned upon and closed nowadays. This one, by virtue of it's age, had slipped through the cracks.

Comment: I guess that note should be added to the question saying how it's still here because of historical reasons, though not deemed fit by modern standards.